# how to cleanup the useEffect function in react js after removing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I am getting this error while using useRef and useEffect in react js.
**how can i cleanup the useEffect in React js this is main topic of this all question **
Dropdown.js:9

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contains')
at HTMLDocument.bodydroptoggler (Dropdown.js:9)
```

here is screenshot:
[image]

I am getting this error when i click on the button named as "drop toggler"

here is code of app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./components/Dropdown";

const options = [
    {
        label: "red color is selected",
        value: "red",
    },
    {
        label: "blue color is selected",
        value: "blue",
    },
    {
        label: "green color is seleted",
        value: "green",
    },
];

const App = () => {
    const [dropactive, setDropactive] = useState(true);
    return (
        <div className="container ui">
            <button
                className="button ui"
                onClick={() => setDropactive(!dropactive)}
            >
                drop toggler
            </button>
            {dropactive ? <Dropdown options={options} /> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

and here is code of dropdown.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const Dropdown = ({ options }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options[0]);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        const bodydroptoggler = (event) => {
            if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                return;
            }
            setOpen(false);
        };
        document.addEventListener("click", bodydroptoggler);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", bodydroptoggler);
            console.log("work");
        };
    }, []);
    const RenderedOptions = options.map((option, index) => {
        if (selected.value === option.value) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (
                <div
                    className="item"
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setSelected(option);
                    }}
                >
                    {option.label}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    return (
        <div ref={ref} className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label className="text label">Select from here:</label>
                <div
                    className={`ui selection dropdown ${
                        open ? "active visible" : ""
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                >
                    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div className="text">{selected.label}</div>
                    <div className={`menu ${open ? "visible transition" : ""}`}>
                        {RenderedOptions}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

here is what i want to perform
i just want to hide that form by clicking on the button.

*how you can run this project*

1. just create a react app
2. put code of app.js to app.js of your project
3. dropdown.js inside the component folder

i hope this all detail will help you i you need anything more just commnet down
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This is whay `useLayoutEffect` is for. It runs it's contents (and cleanups) **synchronously** and avoids the race condition. Here's the stackblitz that proves it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5w7vog

Check out [this post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect#one-special-case) from Kent Dodd's as well:

> One other situation you might want to use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect is if you're updating a value (like a ref) and you want to make sure it's up-to-date before any other code runs. For example:

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It's complicated. Your code generally looks good so it took me a minute to understand why. But here's the **why** - the `Dropdown` component unmounts **before** the cleanup from the effect is run. So the click event still finds the handler, this time with a null reference for the ref (because the ref gets updated immediately).

Your code is correct, idomatic React - but this is an edge case that needs deeper understanding.

As the other answerer already mentioned, just add an optional check. But I thought you might like to know why.

Comment: If it's true that the `useEffect`'s cleanup function runs after a component unmounts (and I believe it is), then how could OPs code also be correct, idiomatic React code?

Comment: Because there are no guarantees when the cleanup function gets called. I’m not sure if this problem might’ve been solved with useLayoutEffect, though. You could be correct if that would solve it

Comment: I suppose if you’re just being pedantic with your comment then yeah, the OP missed on optional on the ref.current. But, what I was implying was they were correctly cleaning up from an effect

Comment: I'm not trying to be pedantic with the comment. I'm trying to determine if your statement about OP's code being idiomatic is misleading. IMO, it's not idiomatic since I've always seen React refs treated as nullable in all cases. That being said, I'm mostly writing React in a type language and I'm forced by the type system to treat the ref as nullable in all cases.

Comment: First answer works perfect for me. But I want to clear my concept of react js cleanup. Is there any way to solve this with the help of cleanup method.

Comment: @jashandeepsingh I have verified that `useLayoutEffect` fixes your issue. [Check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5w7vog)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using optional chaining since ref.current might sometimes be undefined?

`if (ref.current?.contains(event.target))`

Here's a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-butterfly-setzd?file=/src/App.jsc) with the fix.

Also some additional context from [React Ref docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) on why sometimes the ref might be null

> React will assign the current property with the DOM element when the component mounts, and assign it back to null when it unmounts.